# Are 7z-included checksums enough to verify backup integrity?

Tags: backup, 7-zip, checksum

I recently started using uncompressed, encrypted 7z archives for backups. I chose 7z because it has easy to use desktop apps for Windows and Linux, in case I need to recover the data quickly.

I store checksums next to the archive file to detect file corruption. Currently the archive is written to an external HDD and then read again for checksumming. This is necessary because 7z seeks while creating a 7z archive so I can't its output through a pipe. Reading the file again is pretty slow though.

I discovered that 7z has the "t" action to "Test[s] archive files". Running "7z -h" describes it as "Test integrity of archive". Unfortunately that's all help and documentation say about it.
I had a look at the 7z format specification, which seems to include places for CRC checksums of some kind. I also had a glance at the source code, but I didn't understand where to look for. I couldn't find the part responsible for the test action.

So my question is:
**What kind of checksums does 7z store in .7z archives, and are they sufficient to detect file corruption?**

I don't count corruption to the archive metadata, as that is obvious when 7z won't open the archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug a bit deeper, and 7z stores CRC-32 checksums for files in the archive.

The 7z SDK contains a file format description ([a copy of which can be found online here](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/BJOERN/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/7zip/DOC/7zFormat.txt)). However it is pretty short and doesn't tell what the different parts really do.

I found Py7zr [which also documents the 7z file format](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/archive_format.html), in a much more understandable way. The file data is stored in so-called Packed Streams. A CRC-32 checksum is saved for every Packed Stream, which may be checked on extraction.

Additionally there exist CRC-32 checksums for the uncompressed data of every file in the Coders Information header section. When testing an archive with the 7z GUI, it shows the files it checks, so it probably decompresses the files and checks their CRC.

As CRC-32 has a probability of about 2^32 for having an accidental collision when files get corrupted, it should be pretty usable up to a few 100k files in the archive. There also is a [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456825/sfv-crc32-checksum-good-and-fast-enough-to-check-for-common-backup-files) for the suitability of CRC-32 to detect file errors.

As I only have a few thousand files by now, the checksums integrated in the 7z file format should be sufficient to detect file corruption.

Answer (score 3):

With 7-Zip you can display the checksum/hash using several methods,
but unfortunately you have to store the values yourself and compare them manually.

The [7Zip h (Hash) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/hash.htm)
does the following:

> calculates CRC32 for all files in current folder and all subfolders

Comment: Really? "Test" doesn't verify the checksums found in an archive? I would expect that to happen. 32 bit CRC:s should allow to detect quite a bit of file content faults. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: @Hannu: The documentation of the [t command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/test.htm) does not mention hashes, which I take to mean that it verifies the archive but not its contents. I imagine this means stuff like offsets and sizes. The only place where hashes are mentioned is in the above hash command, which works on disk files, not archive items.

Comment: `7z t archive.zip *.doc -r` - `tests *.doc files in archive archive.zip.`
As I read that, the testing is on the content of individual archived files - i.e. there must be a checksum, which gets checked for being correct.

Comment: @Hannu: I have searched for some such mention, and found several posts where the answer was the same as mine. Unfortunately there is no documentation about it.

Comment: I just found that "7z -h" outputs "t : Test integrity of archive" and added that to my question. To me that sounds like verifying checksums, as they are also mentioned in the 7z file format. Maybe we can get definite answers when someone knowing the source code finds this question